# For $F_0(z)=1/(1-z)^i$, verify that $|F_0(z)|\leq e^{\pi/2}$ in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F_0(z)=1/(1-z)^i$, verify that $|F_0(z)|\leq e^{\pi/2}$ in the unit disc, but that $\lim_{r\to 1} F_0(r)$ does not exist.

It's clear that $|F_0(r)|=1$, but I cannot recall how to do function with complex power. As I let $z=a+bi$ and use some equation like $x=\exp(\ln x)$, it becomes even more complicated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The complex power function is defined via $z^w:=\exp(w\text{Log}(z))$ where the $\text{Log}$ is the complex log function.

Answer (score 1):

What do you know about logarithms in the complex plane? First thing you should know is that powers of complex numbers are not well-defined in general. Here, I believe $(1-z)^{i}$ is defined using the principal branch of logarithm. Write $F(z)=e^{-i Log (1-z)}$ and recall definition of $Log (z)$ as $\ln |z|+i\theta$ where $z=|z|e^{i \theta},-\pi < \theta < \pi$. Now can you complete the solution?